# Moving between selected sheets based on time

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a spreadsheet that works like a dashboard and has a userform which shows all sheets. The user can select the sheets he wants and start the presentation which is just moving between the selected sheets based on the specified time.
This is the code:

```
    Public StartStop As Integer, NSheetsSel As Integer, i As Integer, Aux As Integer
Public SheetsSel As Variant
Public Sub StartButton_Click()

StartStop = 1
NSheetsSel = 0
With Me.SheetsBox
    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        If .Selected(i) Then
            NSheetsSel = NSheetsSel + 1
        End If
    Next
    'ReDim SheetsSel(30) As Integer
    ReDim SheetsSel(NSheetsSel) As Integer
    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        If .Selected(i) Then
            SheetsSel(i) = i
        End If
    Next
End With
Aux = 0
Repeat2
End Sub

Public Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim WSheets() As String, size As Integer, i As Integer
    size = Sheets.Count
    ReDim WSheets(size)
    For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
        WSheets(i - 1) = Workbooks("Packaging Dashboard.xlsm").Sheets(i).Name
    Next i
SheetsBox.List = WSheets
End Sub

Public Sub Repeat()
alertTime = Now + TimeValue(TimeP / 86400)
Application.OnTime alertTime, "Repeat2"
End Sub

Public Sub Repeat2()
Dim Test As Integer
Test = SheetsSel(Aux)
If StartStop = 1 Then
Worksheets(Test).Activate
Aux = Aux + 1
If Aux = SheetsSel.Length - 1 Then
Aux = 0
End If
Repeat
End If
End Sub
```

The first problem I have is that it can't `ReDim SheetsSel(NSheetsSel) As Integer` . it shows "Subscript out of range" on `SheetsSel(i) = i`. When I redim it to a specific size `ReDim SheetsSel(30) As Integer`, it passes that part and crashes at `Worksheets(Test).Activate` saying "Subscript out of range". Any thoughts?

Comment: You can't change the type of an array when you redim it. You declared it as Variant at the top and then you try to redim it as Integer. The types need to match.

Comment: Use a dictionary  rather than an array for SheetsSel if you want to use as indices the original sheet indices.

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried to keep as variant and it shows the same error.

Comment: I don't know how to use dictionary. How could I change my code to use it, John? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think your declaration of SheetsSel needs to be `Public SheetsSel() As Integer`. Redim should work after that.

Comment: I already tried this, xdgel. It doesn't work either. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @ExcelDevelopers It is okay to specify a type in a `ReDim` statement applied to a variant variable. The semantics is that it determines the `subtype` of the variable. It is mostly superfluous to do so, but there might be less memory use if you tell VBA that a variant will be holding an array of ints as opposed to an array of unspecified types.

Comment: Oh I see the problem. I'll post it in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a separate index for the SheetsSel array:

```
ReDim SheetsSel(NSheetsSel) As Integer
For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
    If .Selected(i) Then
        n = n + 1
        SheetsSel(n) = i
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided not use the userform and the arrays, so I made it really simple. Thanks to everyone that tried to help me. Here is the code of what I did in case someone have a similar problem. Thanks guys.

```
Public Timep As Date, StartStop As Boolean
Sub StartP()
Timep = Sheets("Present").Range("B1").Value / 86400
StartStop = True
Slide
End Sub
Sub StopP()
StartStop = False
End Sub

Sub Slide()
'
' Slide Macro
'
'
If StartStop Then
    Sheets("1 Day ScoreCard All Packaging").Select
    alertTime = Now + Timep
    Application.OnTime alertTime, "Slide2"
End If
End Sub
Public Sub Slide2()
If StartStop Then
Sheets("1 Day ScoreCard Pail Line").Select
    alertTime = Now + Timep
    Application.OnTime alertTime, "Slide3"
End If
End Sub
Public Sub Slide3()
If StartStop Then
Sheets("1 Day ScoreCard Auto Line").Select
    alertTime = Now + Timep
    Application.OnTime alertTime, "Slide4"
End If
End Sub
Public Sub Slide4()
If StartStop Then
Sheets("1 Day ScoreCard Capping Line").Select
    alertTime = Now + Timep
    Application.OnTime alertTime, "Slide5"
End If
End Sub
Public Sub Slide5()
If StartStop Then
Sheets("1 Day ScoreCard Half Gallon").Select
    alertTime = Now + Timep
    Application.OnTime alertTime, "Slide6"
End If
End Sub
Public Sub Slide6()
If StartStop Then
Sheets("1 Day ScoreCard 2.5").Select
    alertTime = Now + Timep
    Application.OnTime alertTime, "Slide7"
End If
End Sub
Public Sub Slide7()
If StartStop Then
Sheets("1 Day ScoreCare X").Select
    alertTime = Now + Timep
    Application.OnTime alertTime, "Slide"
End If
End Sub
```